# (Rails API backend + React/Redux) uploading images using paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, react-redux

I'm having trouble storing the state correctly for images uploaded by the paperclip gem. Here is my file input in the form:

```
   <input type="file" 
          name="image"
          onChange={event => this.handleFileUpload(event)}
          value={this.state.value}
    />
```

Here is my mapStateToProps function:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
if (state.fileReducer.length > 0) {
    return {
        memes: state.fileReducer
    }
} else {
    return {
        memes: [{top: '', bottom: '', image: ''}]
    }
  }
 }
```

Here is my create action:

```
const createMeme = (meme) => {
return function(dispatch) {
    return Api.createMeme(meme).then(response => {
        dispatch(createMemesSuccess(response));
        return response;
    })
}
```

}

and here is my reducer:

```
export default function fileReducer(state=[], action) {
switch(action.type) {
    case "LOAD_MEMES_SUCCESS": 
        return action.memes
    default:
        return state
}
```

}

When I create a new Meme in the rails console it returns all of the other attributes that go along with *image* (image_file_name etc.)

I'm just not understanding how to process this correctly in my component with react and redux.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Need some more information on this one. What does your action look like? What does the reducer look like? What do you mean when you say you don't know how to process it? Do you mean you fire an action and it actually creates it but you don't know what to do from there?

Comment: Hi! I've updated my question with my action and reducer. I'm able to fire the action and render the text to the page, but the image is not saving correctly when I submit the form.

Comment: Once I have the right data for the image upon submitting the form I imagine I'd make an ajax request to render the image on the page

Comment: Are you getting any errors?